# Sort by largest of two date values from two tables

Tags: mysql

I am working on a simple forum and am struggling when trying to sort the topics when listed - if the topics all have replies then it works fine, if none have replies then it works fine but if they have combination of both then it doesn't work properly. I need to take the largest value out of forum_topics and forum_replies and sort using that value.

I have looked up greatest and it seems to be what I need but it doesn't work for me:

```
SELECT
GREATEST(MAX(forum_topics.topic_date),MAX(forum_replies.reply_date)) as g_date 
from forum_topics 
left join forum_replies on forum_topics.topic_id=forum_replies.reply_topic
where forum_topics.topic_category='$category_id'
GROUP BY forum_topics.topic_id
ORDER BY g_date desc
```

forum_topics

```
topic_id    topic_date          topic_category
1           26/12/2012 23:09    2
2           26/12/2012 10:13    5
3           27/12/2012 02:04    2
4           27/12/2012 02:25    7
5           27/12/2012 02:32    3
6           27/12/2012 02:46    2
8           27/12/2012 02:49    2
9           27/12/2012 16:05    2
10          06/01/2013 19:57    2
11          06/01/2013 20:35    2
12          06/01/2013 20:36    5
```

forum_replies

```
reply_id    reply_date          reply_topic
1           29/12/2012 19:14    1
2           26/12/2012 23:49    3
3           31/12/2012 00:00    1
4           27/12/2012 02:03    1
5           27/12/2012 02:15    3
6           27/12/2012 02:16    3
7           27/12/2012 02:17    3
8           27/12/2012 02:26    4
9           27/12/2012 03:19    3
10          27/12/2012 03:26    3
11          27/12/2012 03:29    3
12          27/12/2012 03:29    3
13          27/12/2012 03:30    3
14          27/12/2012 03:32    3
15      27/12/2012 03:35    3
17          27/12/2012 15:23    8
18          06/01/2013 20:35    2
19          06/01/2013 20:38    1
```

Desire outcome for category id=2:

```
1           06/01/2013 20:38 (reply 19)
11          06/01/2013 20:35 (topic 11)
10          06/01/2013 19:57 (topic 10)
9           27/12/2012 16:05 (topic 9)
3           27/12/2012 03:35 (reply 15)
6           27/12/2012 02:46 (topic 6)
```

Actual output

```
1   06/01/2013 20:38:23 
3   27/12/2012 03:35:33 
6   27/12/2012 02:46:57 
9   27/12/2012 16:05:42 
10  06/01/2013 19:57:33 
11  06/01/2013 20:35:48
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your **sample data**, **expected output** please

Comment: What's your actual output? What isn't working?

Comment: Have updated the actual output and expected output